# Where should I place a return statement for a try/except block?

Tags: python

I have the following try/except block. Since the except block has it's own `return` statement I have 3 possible ways in this scenario where I could place the `return` statement if the `try` block succeeds. Is there a convention or best practice for it?

Version 1:

```
try:
    self.validate()
    self.perform_creation()

except UserException as e:
    show_error(e.message)
    return super().render(request)

return redirect(self.next)  # Return here
```

Version 2:

```py
try:
    self.validate()
    self.perform_creation()
    return redirect(self.next)  # Return here

except UserException as e:
    show_error(e.message)
    return super().render(request)
```

Version 3:

```py
try:
    self.validate()
    self.perform_creation()

except UserException as e:
    show_error(e.message)
    return super().render(request)

else:
    return redirect(self.next)  # Return here
```

Comment: Put any statements that are *not* expected to raise an exception outside the `try` block. In this case the `else` clause is pretty superfluous. These rules of thumb should lead you to your solution.

Comment: I like to reduce branching as much as possible (which often helps to reduce cyclomatic complexity) so I would go for version 1 or 2. Definetly not version 3.

Comment: Splitting "the happy path" makes it harder to follow the flow. It's like listening to someone tell a story that keeps braching out into irrelevant detail.

Comment: For less complexity version 1. for more readability version 2.

Comment: i think the consensus would be: Not 3. And then a bunch of opinionated answers between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put statements that aren't suppose to raise an exception outside de try/catch block. So in your case Version 1 is the best solution.